# Upload Ipa file to App Store as Iphone only with transporter

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-developer, outsystems

I made an mobile app in OutSystems. The app is meant for phone. Apple denied my app because it doesn't work well for Ipad. I don't want to upload it as an Ipad app, but i don't know how to change this. I received an IPA file of OutSystems and i uploaded the app through Transporter. Can someone help me?

I tried to upload the app in Xcode but that didn't work. I used Transporter instead but couldn't find where i can change it to Iphone only.

Comment: All iPhone apps can run on iPad in compatibility mode.  You cannot prevent it.

Comment: What is the specific problem. @Paulw11 is correct (iPhone-only apps run on iPad, and Apple doesn't clearly document this...), but in my experience, the iPad-bad rejections have a specific reason.